# How to dynamically generate the Host URL in Angular (v. 4)

Tags: angular, auth0

So I am using **Auth0** and wanted to know how to dynamically generate the Host URL to set the **redirectUri** property of **WebAuth()** of **auth0**.

```
auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
  clientID: AUTH_CONFIG.clientID,
  domain: AUTH_CONFIG.domain,
  responseType: 'token id_token',
  audience: `https://${AUTH_CONFIG.domain}/userinfo`,
  redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200/#/callback',
  scope: 'openid'
});
```

The purpose is that I don't want to hard-code my host address when switching environments or deploying Angular app. As you can see above I am hard-coding `http://localhost:4200/#/` the redirectUri.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use **window.location.origin**. For example:

```
auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
  clientID: AUTH_CONFIG.clientID,
  domain: AUTH_CONFIG.domain,
  responseType: 'token id_token',
  audience: `https://${AUTH_CONFIG.domain}/userinfo`,
  redirectUri: `${window.location.origin}/#/callback`,
  scope: 'openid'
});
```

Comment: No need to manually add hashStrategy to the **redirectUri** property. Angular will automatically append the **/#**

Answer (score 0):

I posted this here because I figured someone else may have had the same issue.

Here is my solution for AuthService, which is more verbose:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  // Configure Auth0
  hashStrategy = true;

  host = (() => {
    let hostUrl: string;
    let index: number;
    if (this.hashStrategy) {
      hostUrl = window.location.href;
      index = hostUrl.indexOf('#/') + 2; // add 2 to include the hash and forward slash
      hostUrl = hostUrl.slice(0, index);
    } else {
      hostUrl = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname;
      if (window.location.port) {
          hostUrl += ':' + window.location.port + '/';
      }
    }
    return hostUrl;
  })();

  auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
    clientID: AUTH_CONFIG.clientID,
    domain: AUTH_CONFIG.domain,
    responseType: 'token id_token',
    audience: `https://${AUTH_CONFIG.domain}/userinfo`,
    redirectUri: this.host  + 'callback',
    scope: 'openid'
  });
...
}
```

By assigning an anonymous function to an instance property of my AuthService, I am able to generate my host URL for hashStrategy or if it isn't a hashStrategy then setting the instance property hashStrategy to false and then implementing the value into Auth0.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a URL without a specific host to achieve the desired behavior:

```
auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
  clientID: AUTH_CONFIG.clientID,
  domain: AUTH_CONFIG.domain,
  responseType: 'token id_token',
  audience: `https://${AUTH_CONFIG.domain}/userinfo`,
  redirectUri: '/callback',
  scope: 'openid'
});
```

Comment: this didn't work. It broke the auth0 service indicating to me that the redirectUri has to be explicit, which was what started the conundrum.

Comment: use location.hostname + '/callback'

Comment: that still will fall short; remember there is hashStrategy. Plus, it will also not include the protocol or port.